# Is $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}}$ defined at $x=0$?

Tags: functions, real-numbers, infinity

In the context of *projectively extended real line* $\widehat{\mathbb{R}}$, if $f(x)=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}}$, then
$$f(0)=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{0}}=\frac{1}{\infty}=0.$$

But in the context of $\mathbb{R}$, if $f(x)=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}}$, is $f(0)$ undefined or is it zero?

On the one hand, if $g(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ is undefined at $x=0$, then $\frac{1}{g(x)}$ should be undefined as well, therefore in the context of $\mathbb{R}$, $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}}$ should be undefined at $x=0$.

On the other hand, if $g(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ and $x=0$, then $g(x)$ can be either $\infty$ or $-\infty$ and that would be the reason why is it undefined, but if we write $\frac{1}{0}=\pm\infty$ instead of saying that it's undefined, can we use

$$\frac{1}{\infty}=\frac{1}{-\infty}=0$$

and then say that, in the context of $\mathbb{R}$,
$$\frac{1}{\frac{1}{0}}=0?$$

Comment: Your evaluating a limit.  $\frac 1{\frac 1x} = x$.

Comment: In the context of $\mathbb R$, $f(0)$ is undefined because $1/0$ is

Comment: Actually, I'm not asking about $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}}$ or $\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}}$ etc., but pure plugging in $x=0$ to $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}}$. I admit there probably is a mistake somewhere in my post.

Comment: Well, $\infty\notin\Bbb R$ and ${1\over \infty}=0$ sounds more like an agreement.

Comment: "Is undefined" is not a property inherent of an expression, it is a given one. When a text says that $\frac{1}{x}$ is undefined at $x=0$, they are giving it that property. Another text can define it at $x=0$. In the context of Calculus, it is common to leave $\frac{1}{x}$ undefined at $x=0$, and consider a composition of functions defined only when each function composed is defined at the corresponding value. So, $\frac{1}{1/x}$, being the composition of $1/x$ with itself, would be required to be undefined at $x=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the reals $\dfrac 1{\left(\frac 1x\right)}$ is undefined for $x=0$.  The limit as $x \to 0$ does exist and is $0$.  It is a removable singularity in the function, which just looks like a hole in the graph.  You can extend the function to one that is continuous everywhere by defining $f(0)=0$.

The same thing happens for $g(x)=\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}$.  This function has a removable singularity at $x=1$, but if you add in the definition $g(1)=2$ it becomes continuous.

Comment: For the result to be defined in $\mathbb{R}$, is it necessary to take e.g. $\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}}$, or is $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}}$ sufficient?

Comment: To have the result defined, you just define it.  Technically you should define a new function $h(x)$ by $h(0)=0, h(x)=f(x)$ if $x \neq 0$.  It is a little abuse to just define $f(0)=0$.  Having done so, we note that $f(x)$ is continuous, which requires the limit from both sides.  Your comment has it backwards in that $\lim_{x \to 0}$ is more restrictive than $\lim_{x \to 0^+}$

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to define the object $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{0}}$ in the real numbers without presuming the definition of $\frac{1}{0}$, but if $\frac{1}{0}$ is defined, i.e. is equal to some real number, then
$$
1 = 0 \cdot \frac{1}{0} = 0
$$
which is absurd. The best we can hope to do is to define $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{0}}$ not as a real number beholden to the properties of the real numbers but as some kind of symbol that extends the usual operations of addition and multiplication on the real numbers. This is exactly what we do when we create the extended real numbers.

Comment: When you define something, this doesn't imply that that definition needs to work in every conceivably additional context. You can define $1/(1/0)$ without defining $1/0$ and you can define $1/0$ without having to define $0\cdot (1/0)$ and even worse, having it satisfy the cancellation property $1=0\cdot (1/0)$. In fact both of these actions are commonly done in mathematics. $1/(1/0)$ is defined as $0$, when one removes the singularity and $1/0$ is defined as $\infty$ when one compactifies the plane.